# nginx string.match non posix

Tags: nginx, lua

I got a string (str1) and I want to extract anything after pattern "mycode=",

```
local str1 = "ServerName/codebase/?mycode=ABC123";
local tmp1 = string.match(str1, "mycode=%w+");
local tmp2 = string.gsub(tmp1,"mycode=", "");
```

From the logs,

```
tmp1 => mycode=ABC123
tmp2 => ABC123
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? I do belive lua strings do not follow the POSIX standard (due to the size of the code base).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a capture in your pattern to control what you get back from `string.match`.

From the lua [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.match) (emphasis mine):

> Looks for the first match of pattern in the string s. If it finds one, then match **returns the captures from the pattern**; otherwise it returns nil. If pattern specifies no captures, then the whole match is returned. A third, optional numerical argument init specifies where to start the search; its default value is 1 and can be negative.

It works like this:

```
> local str1 = "ServerName/codebase/?mycode=ABC123"
> local tmp1 = string.match(str1, "mycode=%w+")
> print(tmp1)
mycode=ABC123
> local tmp2 = string.match(str1, "mycode=(%w+)")
> print(tmp2)
ABC123
```

Comment: Thank you @Etan Reisner! That's exactly what I was looking for! :)